# signal handler in mulitprocess.process class , can't get class's val

Tags: python, signals, multiprocessing

Use this example , I want capture signal .and print var in class.

```
import signal
import time
import multiprocessing

class test(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(test,self).__init__()
        self.a = []

    def handle(self,sig,frm):
        print "in hander  selfid    " , id(self)
        print "in handler self.a    " , self.a
        print "in handler self.a id " , id(self.a)

    def run(self):

        self.a = [1 ,2] 
        print "in run selfid        " , id(self)
        print "in run self.a id     " , self.a 
        print "in run self.a id is  " , id(self.a)
        while 1:
            time.sleep(10)

test_1 = test()

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,test_1.handle)
test_1.run()
time.sleep(2)

signal.alarm(1)
```

Use ubunut12.04 python 2.7 The answer is like :

python test.py

```
in run selfid         139880313607120
in run self.a id      [1, 2]
in run self.a id is   139880313975872
in hander  selfid     139880313607120
in handler self.a     []
in handler self.a id  139880313580432
```

while I expect the answer:

```
in handler self.a is [1,2]
```

Putting `signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,test_1.handle)` in `self.__init__`  doesn't work too.

I use this method to get: when the parent was killed by SIGTERM. the signal handler 
defun in parent , will iterate it's child process list to kill it. And register it in `__init__` fun. the child list get in run() fun like the example.
I print the id of self. when the handler is called , self is same . however , self.a is 
different .
As the print show , run was called first , then handler .so self.a should be same ?
So , what's problem here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to print PID of the process that catches and handles SIGALRM, you'll see that it's a parent process, not the child:

```py
    ...
    def handle(self,sig,fem):
        print "in handler pid: ", os.getpid()

...
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM,test_1.handle)
test_1.start()
print "Parent PID: ", os.getpid()
print "Child PID: ", test_1.pid
...
```

Output:

```
Parent PID:  3137
Child PID:  3138
...
in handler pid:  3137 <-- parent
...
```

You need to modify your code so that:

1. The signal handler is set *inside* the child process
2. The signal is sent *to* child process

```py
class test(multiprocessing.Process):
    ...
    def handle(self,sig,fem):
        ...

    def run(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle)
        ...

...
test_1.start()
time.sleep(2)

os.kill(test_1.pid, signal.SIGALRM)
```

Comment: Thank you . you are right. I had try put in the __init__ func .In fact process was create after start() was called .